# How to import node library into webpage using CDN

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-scraping

So I've created a simple program using node.js and a couple of libraries using `puppeteer` and `kijiji-scraper` from npm and I want to run it on a webpage like Github pages. In the past, I've had success using a CDN to import the node library I needed to do so by following the instructions on the readme. But for these packages, there aren't any instructions for importing using CDN. Is it just not possible to do so or am I missing something?

Packages:

- https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/kijiji-scraper
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS and the web have fundamentally different moduling systems. You won't be able to import libraries written for Node in the web. If the libraries are pure JavaScript libraries (not relying on the standard library or native modules) or are browser-based libraries relying on the DOM, then you can use Browserify to compile the library's source code into a single file and include that on the web page with a `<script>`. Otherwise, you'll need to restructure your application around this limitation.

In your case however, it looks like Kijiji is a client-side library and Browserify will be your solution here.

You can come to this conclusion by skimming some of its source code. You'll notice that there's a `require` call in it. The `require` function doesn't exist on the DOM API and hence will throw the error you're getting.

The solution I would use in your case would be a) Grunt or Gulp or b) compiling the code and import them statically.

If you have a more complex build chain, I would suggest including the browserify stage in it. I would also not use the CDN based library, rather use the NPM library. The browserify stage will *bundle* the library and all required dependencies into a single file that can be used in HTML

```
<script src="/static/kijiji.js"></script>
<script src="/app/index.js"></script>
```

*I'm not sure what your file structure looks like but you get the idea.*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I tried browserify to bundle the dependencies but its giving me an error bundling puppeteer ```Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\w\Desktop\Scraper\node_modules\puppeteer\utils\browser\WebSocket  from 'C:\Users\w\Desktop\Scraper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib'```, is it because it's not a client-side library? But it has a require function just like the kijiji-scraper library. I've never used grunt/gulp, I've looked into it but I'm not sure what I need it for. Also you suggested compiling the code and importing them statically, but isn't javascript interpreted?

Comment: How are you running browserify?

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that Kijiji-scraper itself depends on other libraries which are not designed to run in the browser. I realise now that Kijiji-scraper is actually a library written for nodejs. Meaning you won't be able to run it in the browser and in fact the latter option from above is going to be required.

Comment: You mean b) compiling the code and import them statically? I'm not sure what you mean by that, how do you compile javascript isn't it interpreted? and also what is meant by importing statically?

Comment: Ahh, yes. My bad. So JavaScript can be transpiled meaning the program does the sand thing, it's just written differently. In Kijiji's case, the code is simply split into multiple files. When I say *compile* I don't mean actually compile it to machine code, I just mean merging everything into a bundle ( a single file ) and importing statically means the browser receives that bundle without any further modification to it.

Comment: I see, so I should use browserify to bundle the dependencies? It's giving me an error though (listed above) any idea why?

Comment: You will have to design your app around a server side ad scraper